# Quotient space of $\mathbb{S}^1\times [0,1]$obtained by identifying points in the circle $\mathbb{S}^1\times \{0\}$ that differ by $2π /3$ rotation

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

**The quotient space of  $\mathbb{S}^1\times [0,1]$ obtained by identifying points in the circle $\mathbb{S}^1\times \{0\}$ that differ by $2π /3$ rotation and identifying points in the circle $\mathbb{S}^1\times \{1\}$ that differ by $2π/2$ rotation.**

**My attempt:** I will calculate the homology groups using the succession of mayer vietoris, for this, we call $X=\mathbb{S}^1\times [0,1]/{\sim}$, $U=X-(\mathbb{S}^1\times \{0\})$ and $V=X-(\mathbb{S}^1\times \{1\})$ then we will have that $U\simeq \mathbb{S}^1$, $V\simeq \mathbb{S}^1$ and $U\cap V$ is contractile, with these choices I get to that $H_0(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}$, $H_1(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}^2$, $H_n(X)=0$ if $n>1$,  but I think I am wrong, could someone tell me if This is good? Thank you.

Comment: You didn't quotient in U and V. The intersection looks like a cylinder, not contractible.

Comment: @AHusain 
You're right, actually $U\cap V\simeq \mathbb{S}^1$

Comment: @AHusain 
What do you mean by "You didn't quotient in U and V", what else do I have to correct? If I am reasoning and solving the problem in the right way?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the half-cylinders $\mathbb{S}^1\times [\frac{1}{2} ,1]/\sim $ and $\mathbb{S}^1\times [0,\frac{1}{2} ]/\sim $ and use the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, we will obtain
$$
H_{\bullet } (\mathbb{S}^1\times\{\frac{1}{2}\} )\rightarrow H_{\bullet } (\mathbb{S}^1\times [\frac{1}{2} ,1]/\sim )\oplus H_{\bullet } (\mathbb{S}^1\times [0,\frac{1}{2} ]/\sim )\rightarrow H_{\bullet } (\mathbb{S}^1\times [0,1]/\sim )\xrightarrow{+1}
$$
and observe that the first term is just $\mathbb{Z} $ when $\bullet =1$ and $0$ otherwise, with generator mapping onto $(3,2)$ via the given homomorphism, and hence the long exact sequence gives $H_{\bullet } (\mathbb{S}^1\times [0,1]/\sim )\cong (\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z} )/(3,2)\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}$.(Thanks for the comment, I made a mistake here, and now it's corrected.)

Comment: That should be "...when $\bullet=0,1$ and $0$ otherwise...". I would like to know if $\mathbb{S}^1\times\{\frac{1}{2}\}\simeq\mathbb{S}^1 ,  \mathbb{S}^1\times [\frac{1}{2} ,1]/{\sim}\simeq\mathbb{S}^1   , \mathbb{S}^1\times [0,\frac{1}{2} ]/{\sim}\simeq\mathbb{S}^1 $?

Comment: @user482152 The first one is obvious, the second one follows from retracting the space by scaling the parameter $t$, to $1$ and the third one to $0$. Then note that the quotient of a circle is a circle as well, but the induced homomorphism will have a coefficient.

Comment: Perfect! Another thing: Why $(\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z} )/(3,2)\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: @user482152 In fact I'm not sure if it is right... I'm not quite familiar with this purely algebraic computations.

Comment: In fact, $(\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z})/(3,2)\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}$.  To see this, consider the map $f:\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(a,b) = 2a-3b$.  This map is surjective because $1 = f(-1,-1)$ generates $\mathbb{Z}$.  Its kernel is $(3,2)\mathbb{Z}$, so by the first isomorphism theorem, the result follows.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Ah you're right. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: I'm happy to delete my comment, if you prefer (and then you could edit your post to not even mention the comment).  It's up to you.